# Open source github like web interface

Tags: git, github, open-source

I am interested in an open source github clone. I know I can host my own git repository and push to it. I would like a web interface for it. Alot of features that github or bit bucket offers.

Why not just use github? For no other reason than to just play with new technology.

In short, Im looking to have my own github on a server I own.

Is there such a thing out there?

Unfortunately, googling `github clone` or `open source github` returns actual github pages as those are both key terms in relationship to github itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) might be useful. It is a self-hosted Git management software. You could also try out [Github Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/) for 45 days and see how that fits your needs.

Comment: Wow, took just a minute to install. Thanks, Gitlabs worked.

Answer (score 4):

try Gitorious
Its not exactly like github but its free. some what similar to github, has the folder views

http://gitorious.org/

Comment: @lynvie http://getgitorious.com/installer

Comment: @MaxEhrlich, oops, yes it can run from your own website. Deleting my incorrect comment. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note that Gitorious has been acquired by gitlab.